# How to automatically delete noise (artifacts) in time series data in R

Tags: r, signal-processing, artifacts, noise-reduction

If I have the following data:

```
structure(list(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 
62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 
78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 
94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 
108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 
121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 
134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 
147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 
160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 
173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 
186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 
199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 
212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 
225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 
238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 
251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 
264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 
277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 
290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 
303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 
316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 
329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 
342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 
355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 
368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 
381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 
394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 
407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 
420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 
433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 
446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 
459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 
472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 
485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 
498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 
511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 
524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 
537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 
550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 
563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 
576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 
589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 
602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 
615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 
628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 
641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 
654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 
667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 
680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 
693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 699, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 
706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 
719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 
732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 
745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 
758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 769, 770, 
771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 782, 783, 
784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 
797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802, 803, 804, 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 
810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817, 818, 819, 820, 821, 822, 
823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 
836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 
849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 
862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 
875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 
888, 889, 890, 891, 892, 893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 
901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 913, 
914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 
927, 928, 929, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 
940, 941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 
953, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 
966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 
979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 990, 991, 
992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999), y = c(99, 100, 97, 95, 
94, 92, 90, 91, 91, 92, 95, 99, 99, 100, 101, 101, 101, 102, 
104, 106, 107, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 113, 114, 117, 
117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 146, 124, 124, 125, 123, 
126, 111, 110, 109, 108, 121, 122, 122, 123, 124, 124, 124, 123, 
122, 120, 120, 120, 121, 122, 123, 123, 125, 125, 126, 126, 126, 
126, 126, 125, 125, 125, 126, 127, 127, 129, 130, 131, 131, 131, 
131, 130, 130, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 127, 127, 127, 127, 
127, 127, 128, 130, 131, 132, 132, 132, 131, 131, 131, 131, 132, 
132, 133, 132, 132, 127, 126, 125, 125, 128, 128, 129, 130, 130, 
130, 131, 131, 132, 132, 132, 132, 131, 130, 129, 129, 128, 128, 
128, 128, 129, 129, 129, 128, 128, 128, 127, 127, 126, 126, 126, 
127, 127, 127, 127, 126, 126, 126, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 128, 
128, 129, 129, 130, 130, 129, 130, 131, 131, 131, 131, 130, 131, 
131, 130, 130, 130, 130, 129, 129, 129, 130, 130, 131, 132, 133, 
134, 134, 134, 134, 133, 132, 130, 128, 126, 126, 127, 127, 130, 
131, 132, 133, 135, 136, 135, 134, 131, 130, 130, 130, 132, 134, 
135, 135, 135, 134, 132, 131, 130, 128, 127, 126, 126, 127, 128, 
128, 128, 129, 130, 130, 131, 131, 131, 131, 130, 129, 127, 126, 
126, 126, 126, 127, 127, 128, 128, 130, 130, 131, 131, 130, 129, 
129, 128, 128, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 132, 132, 131, 131, 131, 
132, 132, 132, 131, 130, 129, 128, 128, 129, 129, 130, 129, 129, 
129, 129, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 129, 129, 128, 128, 127, 127, 
126, 127, 129, 130, 131, 132, 135, 135, 135, 134, 133, 130, 130, 
130, 130, 130, 130, 132, 134, 135, 134, 133, 132, 132, 132, 131, 
131, 131, 131, 131, 132, 132, 132, 131, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 
130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 
135, 135, 136, 135, 135, 135, 135, 134, 133, 132, 132, 132, 132, 
132, 133, 134, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 134, 134, 134, 135, 135, 
135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 135, 135, 135, 135, 134, 135, 136, 
137, 138, 138, 138, 139, 138, 138, 137, 137, 136, 136, 136, 136, 
136, 136, 135, 134, 133, 132, 132, 132, 132, 131, 131, 131, 132, 
132, 133, 133, 133, 133, 132, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 134, 135, 
136, 136, 136, 136, 135, 134, 133, 132, 131, 131, 132, 132, 132, 
132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 133, 133, 133, 132, 132, 132, 
132, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 135, 135, 136, 137, 
137, 136, 136, 136, 137, 137, 137, 137, 138, 138, 138, 137, 136, 
135, 133, 132, 132, 132, 133, 134, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 
135, 134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 119, 118, 118, 134, 135, 135, 
122, 122, 122, 84, 84, 84, 84, 55, 58, 74, 141, 140, 139, 133, 
131, 128, 128, 127, 128, 130, 132, 132, 132, 132, 131, 130, 130, 
131, 132, 133, 135, 136, 136, 136, 135, 134, 132, 131, 130, 131, 
132, 132, 134, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 134, 134, 134, 133, 135, 
136, 136, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 138, 
137, 136, 136, 135, 135, 134, 134, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 135, 
136, 136, 137, 137, 136, 136, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 134, 132, 
132, 132, 133, 135, 135, 134, 134, 132, 131, 131, 131, 132, 135, 
135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 134, 134, 133, 133, 133, 132, 133, 133, 
133, 134, 135, 137, 137, 137, 136, 134, 133, 132, 132, 132, 132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 136, 136, 137, 136, 136, 136, 136, 135, 135, 
135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 134, 134, 133, 133, 132, 132, 
132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 133, 135, 139, 140, 141, 141, 140, 139, 
137, 135, 133, 133, 133, 133, 134, 135, 135, 135, 135, 136, 135, 
135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 137, 138, 140, 140, 
139, 139, 137, 135, 136, 134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 
134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 135, 135, 136, 136, 137, 137, 
137, 137, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 134, 134, 
133, 133, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 133, 133, 
133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 135, 137, 137, 137, 136, 135, 135, 
135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 79, 79, 
74, 66, 66, 63, 103, 102, 138, 138, 139, 138, 137, 121, 121, 
121, 121, 121, 109, 109, 110, 109, 109, 73, 73, 73, 73, 48, 48, 
40, 40, 39, 38, 70, 130, 140, 140, 140, 139, 139, 138, 138, 138, 
138, 138, 138, 138, 139, 140, 140, 140, 81, 81, 82, 128, 143, 
143, 142, 141, 138, 136, 136, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 
137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 136, 136, 136, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 
135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 134, 135, 
135, 136, 138, 138, 138, 138, 138, 138, 138, 138, 138, 138, 139, 
140, 141, 141, 140, 139, 139, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 136, 136, 
136, 136, 136, 140, 141, 143, 145, 126, 125, 111, 110, 120, 119, 
133, 118, 119, 108, 98, 99, 108, 108, 108, 120, 135, 135, 135, 
137, 119, 119, 119, 97, 97, 97, 71, 70, 70, 70, 70, 45, 45, 49, 
52, 52, 50, 50, 50, 87, 80, 112, 123, 108, 120, 120, 120, 122, 
122, 110, 122, 120, 99, 99, 99, 99, 108, 121, 136, 137, 138, 
138, 140, 140, 142, 142, 141, 140, 115, 115, 85, 85, 85, 85, 
85, 85, 102, 142, 142, 142, 141, 139, 136, 120, 120, 108, 99, 
91, 100, 100, 110, 110, 110, 122, 122, 137, 137, 100, 100, 100
)), row.names = c(NA, -999L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("x", "y"))
```

**Plot:**

[image]

The red points represent the ones that are considered noise (or artifacts). What I need to do is to detect these points through a function and delete them.

Of course, these red points are not 100% accurate, I am just giving an example to show the data I want to keep and what I want to delete.

I tried applying a butterworth filter but this is not what I need. It does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You might be interested in the answer to this prior question [How to detect and fix abnormal values on plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44713124/4752675)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, assuming your data was assigned to `DF`, we can approximate the relationship between x an y via loess:

```
plot(y ~ x, data = DF)
span_parameter <- 0.15
outlier_threshold <- 1.2

lo <- loess.smooth(DF$x, DF$y, span = span_parameter)
lines(lo$x, lo$y, lwd = 3)
lines(lo$x, lo$y * outlier_threshold, lwd = 3, col = 2)
lines(lo$x, lo$y / outlier_threshold, lwd = 3, col = 2)
```

[image: loess_plot]

You can use `approxfun` to decide which points are outliers or not:

```
f1 <- approxfun(lo$x, lo$y * outlier_threshold)
(wh1 <- which(DF$y > f1(DF$x)))
# [1] 40 959 960 961 962 963 964 965 966 967 977 978 979 980 981 982 995 996

f2 <- approxfun(lo$x, lo$y / outlier_threshold)
(wh2 <- which(DF$y < f2(DF$x)))
# [1] 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 772 773 774 775 776 777 778 779 790 791 792 793
# [20] 794 795 796 797 798 799 800 801 802 803 804 805 823 824 825 910 911 923 924
# [39] 925 926 927 928 929 930 931 932 933 934 935 936 937 938 939 940 970 971 972
# [58] 973 974 975
```

Adjust `span_parameter` and `outlier_threshold` to your convenience.

**EDIT:**

My response was more of a general one, but it seems your data could be better approximated by a log(log()):

```
DF$x <- DF$x + 1
logEstimate <- lm(y~log(log(50+x))-1,data=DF)
plot(y ~ x, data = DF)
lines(DF$x, logEstimate$fitted.values, lwd = 3)
lines(DF$x, logEstimate$fitted.values * outlier_threshold, lwd = 3, col = 2)
lines(DF$x, logEstimate$fitted.values / outlier_threshold, lwd = 3, col = 2)
```

[image: loglog]

Comment: I assume this is data from a high pass filter. I'm not very knowledgeable in that area but basically the ideal case would be to approximate the function that best describes such a filter, not loess or log(log())

Comment: actually your first example fits much better for my purpose.. this saved me hours! thanks for the update anyways.. I am going to use it for other data I have

Comment: oh, and by the way, you can generate sequences of numbers just with 0:999, not c(0, 1, ..., 999)